# Finding kernel density area

Tags: r, gps, kernel-density

I've been using the R package adehabitatHR to find kernel density contours for some penguins and that has all worked fine. However, when I use mcp or kernel.area to find the area within 50% and 95% contours, I'm getting some terribly low estimates in ha. The birds are travelling 30-80km, but the area estimates are coming back as 3.087401 x 10^-7ha. Previous data showed area estimates of 4000-6000ha.
Does anyone know what might be happening?
Thanks!

```
    #please ignore all the libraries, I'm new to R and keep them all up
    library(adehabitatHR)
    library(sp)
    library(rgdal)
    library(raster)        
    F14A <- read_csv("74F314A f.csv")
    str(F14A)
    loc <- F14A[, c("Latitude", "Longitude")]
    str(loc)
    # Change Lat & Long to spatial points
    loc <- as.matrix.data.frame(loc)
    loc <- SpatialPoints(loc)
    ## Estimation of KUD
    ud <- kernelUD(loc, h = "href", grid = 100, same4all = FALSE,
           kern = c("bivnorm"), extent = 1)
    mcp(loc, percent=100)
    mcp.area(loc,percent=seq(50,95, by=5), unin = c("m"),
        unout = c("ha"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The contour plots appeared to be fine, they fit well onto the map and followed the tracks I had. The map was a shapefile that also had GPS coordinates built into it.

The issue was that my points were not correctly transforming. For anyone else with the same issue, I used the following code to transform it to UTM zone 55, and then the kernel.area function worked perfectly.

```
    longlatcoor<-SpatialPoints(cbind(F14A$Longitude,F14A$Latitude), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
    # converting
    utmcoord<-spTransform(longlatcoor,CRS("+proj=utm +south +zone=55 +datum=WGS84"))
    utmcoord #just to double check the transformation has occured
    kud<-kernelUD(utmcoord, h="href", grid=100, hlim = c(0.1, 1.5), kern = c("bivnorm"), extent = 0.5,boundary=barrier)
    image(kud)
    kernel.area(kud,percent=seq(50,95,by=5),unin=("m"),unout=("ha"))
```

This produced GPS values like lat 319187.6 long 5807109, and the final kernel areas in hectares are: 50% = 1153.162, 95% = 7025.186, which is much closer to what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious about your kernel bandwidth.  If you're using a function that calculates the bandwidth for you, there's a chance that whatever optimization it does is getting stuck at far too small a value to be useful (it's happened to me) - too small a kernel bandwidth will result in far too small a kernel density area.

If there's an implementation of `contour()` for the functions you're using, I'd be tempted to `plot(contour(ud))` to see if it looks like a nice contour map (or not!)  If not, try setting the kernel bandwidth to some different values to see how the results behave.

It may seem like an erudite point, but bandwidth selection is a crucial and non-trivial piece of any analysis involving kernel density.  And unfortunately, there are times that black-box software doesn't select a bandwidth that is *as* study-appropriate as you (the subject-matter expert) can.